# Cleaning an Excel table (replace text)

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xls

I have a program that scrapes a table from a website and puts it into an xls table. However, most of the data has to be numbers and some cells might have things like 257,2x , ȻC , KL1 etc. I couldn't figure out an easy way to replace the extra characters with "" as apparently Apache POI doesn't allow this?
So how would you suggest I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

```
int kansio = 1;
    Document doc3 = Jsoup.connect("https://ravit.is.fi/paivanravit/").get();
    Element table2 = doc3.select("table").get(5);
    Elements links2 = table2.select("a[href]"); // a with href
    for (Element link3 : links2) {
        int asd1 = 1;
        new File("C:\\sheets\\lahto-" + kansio).mkdir();
        Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://ravit.is.fi/paivanravit/" + link3.attr("href")).get();
        Elements links = doc2.select("[href*=hevoset]");
        for (Element link2 : links) {

            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://ravit.is.fi/" + link2.attr("href")).get();
                String filename = "C:\\sheets\\lahto-" + kansio + "/" + asd1 + ".xls";
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
                for (Element asd : doc.select("#valittu_public > table > tbody > tr > td > form > table > tbody")) {
                    int rownum = 0;
                    for (Element row : asd.select("tr")) {
                        HSSFRow exlrow = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                        int cellnum = 0;
                        for (Element tds : row.select("td")) {
                            StringUtils.isNumeric("");
                            HSSFCell cell = exlrow.createCell(cellnum++);
                            cell.setCellValue(tds.text());    
                        }
                    }
                }
            sheet.shiftRows(2 ,500 ,-1);
            int ttt = 1;
            while (ttt < 500) {
                sheet.shiftRows(ttt ,500 ,-1);
                ttt++;
            }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        workbook.close();
        asd1++;

        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        }
        }
        kansio++;
        }
```

Comment: Please do not asking multiple questions at once in one question. A question here should really be only one question. To the question about different cell types: [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) provides multiple `setCellValue` methods not only `setCellValue(String)` the last is the only one you seems to use.

Comment: After your edit the question is nor more unclear now. What "extra characters" you need replacing "with """? And why shall `apache poi` doing that? What about using `Java`'s string replacement methods instead?